# Casting AFHTTPRequestOperation.responseString as NSDictionary stays as NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking

```
          if (operation.response.statusCode == 404) {
              NSDictionary *res = (NSDictionary *)operation.responseString;
              NSLog(@"res: %@ %@", res, res.class);

res: {".. a bunch of valid json that validates on json.lint.org"} __NSCFString
```

crash:

```
 <Error>: -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16c21400
 <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16c21400'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x26e46fef 0x350f8c8b 0x26e4c409 0x26e4a327 0x26d79e78 0x9b0bb 0x637e3 0x4de173 0x4de15f 0x4e1e45 0x26e0c609 0x26e0ad09 0x26d57201 0x26d57013 0x2e636201 0x2a4fba59 0x7f369 0x35684aaf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting does not mean that the string would become a dictionary. It is just a way to silence the compiler. The `responseString` is a string and thus should be treated as such. But as I remember there should be a way to get your desired dictionary:

The success block has a `responseObject` parameter which is most likely an instance of `NSData`. It can be converted to `NSDictionary` by using `NSJSONSerialization`.

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization jsonObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is not in the responseString, but in the responseObject, if you are using AFJSONRequest/ResponseSerializers.  See the following code:

```
    - (void)makeAsyncRequest:(NSString *) urlString {
    // Send asynchronous request
    [appDelegate initiateNetworkActivityCounter];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:70 ];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET" ];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


    [manager GET:request.URL.absoluteString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self notifyOnFinishedLoading:(NSDictionary *) responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self notifyOnError];
    }];
}
```

The line with notifyOnFinishedLoading shows you how to send the responseObject as an NSDictionary.  You must also be careful that sometimes JSON will send back an NSArray instead of an NSDictionary, depending on your incoming JSON.